# Add Derived Field to Django Admin Change Form

Tags: python, django, django-admin, modeladmin

I'd like to add a derived field to a default ModelAdmin.fieldsets like I would by specifying a method and adding it to the ModelAdmin.list_display property, but there doesn't seem to be an easy way to do that (if there is ANY way to do that).

The default Django Admin list view seems to have a lot more options than the change form view does.

Let's say I have two fields for a location: latitude and longitude, and instead of displaying them on a change form I want to display a Google Maps Static Map image instead - I already have a method that will return the src url for the image - I just need a way to add that image to the model change form instead of showing those two fields.

Answer (score 4):

If you write a method and add it to ModelAdmin.readonly_fields, it will appear on the change view.

Answer (score -2):

customize admin view http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#ref-contrib-admin

Comment: Not sure what you mean, and there are no examples in the one paragraph of documentation. Can you elaborate with an example?

Comment: you can create custom view like ever you want in django admin